# Validation insert date Java

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

I'm working in Java 8 in Spring Boot, and I have two attributes (`dateBegin` and `dateEnd`) and I want to insert a `dateBegin` value but it mustn't already exist as an interval in the database.
Sample data example:

```
DATE_BEGIN   DATE_END
10-02-2020   15-02-2020
16-02-2020   20-02-2020
22-02-2020   26-02-2020
02-02-2020   05-02-2020
```

If the database contains:

> `dateBegin = 15/01/2020` and `dateEnd = 20/01/2020;`

Then if I want to insert `dateBegin = 18/01/2020` it should not be accepted.
On the other hand if I insert `dateBegin = 21/01/2020`, it should be accepted.

Comment: Cool. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? You're image mentions "DB_TABLE", are we talking SQL here? Or a HashMap?

Comment: sql ,im working on a springboot app

Comment: Do you want to perform the validation in java code?

Comment: @Abra yes exactly

Comment: What database? What data type?

Comment: Do you mean you want to forbid entries where the interval of one row would overlap chronologically the interval of another row?

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems easier to do the validation in SQL.
I would start with the following query.

```
select count(*)
  from DATABASE_TABLE
 where dateBegin between DATE_BEGIN and DATE_END
```

Then I would check the value returned by the query. If the count is greater than zero, then `dateBegin` is invalid.